# Allowing users to make template- Scan code for functions

Tags: php, function, templates, filter

I am currently creating a web app and I would like to allow my users to create a template. I would only allow them to use HTML and some functions to get some values, so I have some functions like
`getDescription();` but since its PHP I also have other function (e.g. `phpinfo();`) which I don't want them to use.

Is it possible to set a filter (like `in_array`) to check if functions other than declared are used?
Or is there an Template engine or something else which does that.

I am very new to templating and I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are only creating HTML templates, you could allow them to put for example;

```
<div>
[PHP]getDescriptions()[PHP]
</div>

<div>
[PHP]phpinfo()[/PHP]
</div>
```

Then in your parsing file when they save or whatever, you could have

```
$allowedFunctions = array('getDescriptions');

$input = '';//html from the template
foreach($allowedFunctions as $key => $value){
    $myVal = $value();
    $input = str_replace('[PHP]'.$value.'()[/PHP]',$myVal,$input);
}
```

This would replace [PHP]getDescriptions()[/PHP] with whatever is returned from getDescriptions()...

and phpinfo() wouldnt change.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if a function exists with [function_exists](http://www.php.net/function_exists). If you want them to use the functions you defined for that purpose only you could prefix those function with something like 'tpl_*". like this:

```
function tpl_getDescription() {/*code here*/}
```

and then when you user tries to implement a function like getDescription you add "tpl_" to it and check if that function exists with `function_exists()`.

```
if(function_exists('tpl_' . $userFuncName))
{
    call_user_func('tpl_' . $userFuncName)
}
```

that way even if the user tries to evoke a native php function tpl_ will be prefixed and if will return false.

Comment: I guess I will combine this solution with @Don Relentless

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could easily make a script that enumerates all user functions in an external file. Lets say you have this "template", `template.php` :

```
<?
function getDescription() {
}
function userFunc() {
}
function anotherFunction() {
}
?>
```

then you could get a list of all functions in `template.php` this way :

```
<?
include('template.php');
$functions = get_defined_functions();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($functions['user']);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

would output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => getdescription
    [1] => userfunc
    [2] => anotherfunction
)
```

I would call this script through AJAX, like `getfunctions.php?file=template.php` which returned a JSON with all user functions inside template.php.

Comment: Where does the `['user']` come from when `print_r($functions['user'])`?

Comment: See [get_defined_functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php) - it is simply a part of the array this function returns. There is an `internal` branch and a `user` branch in the array. Think this is much better than looking manually for particular function names.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. But I will go for the one from Relentless